# html or php list of directory files

Tags: php, html

So I have an Apache web server running off of a raspberry pi. I don't have phpmyadmin or cpanel. I currently have a website running within the directory /var/www/. Within this directory are all off my html and php files that run the website.

The problem is that I sometimes create a file to test out a line of code and forget about the name or that the file is even there. I suppose that what I want is a page on my site that displays all of the files from within the directory /var/www/ as clickable links and in alphabetical order. I have been poking around google and other forums but it seems that not many people have run into the same problems as me. I understand that this is kind of a weird request but any help would be really useful.

Comment: hi, you can see the files on that directory if you do not have an index web(e.g. index.html, index.php or index.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use scandir PHP function:

```
<?php
$dir    = '/tmp';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
print_r($files1);
?>
```

That will show an array of files on your folder. Add that to a files.php file, then you can access to it through a web browser. To display files on the current folder, change $dir value to '.'

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Comment: Thank you very much however, I put this code onto the page and it did nothing. Is there something i'm not doing correctly?

Comment: Give details about what you did. 1. Check the PHP version, 2. the file should be .php to be interpreted. Also I supposed that you have PHP installed. If not, install it. You can't access the file system from an HTML page.

Comment: Thank you vary much. As it turned out I did not have php installed. I retried the code and it worked except that it displayed the file names on one line and I still have know idea how to make the filenames links to their pages but it is not really important. Thank you again.

Comment: Just process the array of file names and output the html you need to be in your page. You need to know a little PHP and HTML, there is plenty of information online.